# where can I find a listing of the methods for neo4j 3.0 driver session .run .then etc

Tags: javascript, session, neo4j

I am new to Neo4j and going through a tutorial that uses neo4j v2. I want to use v3.0 but functions like:

```
User.get = function (id, callback) {
    var qp = {
        query: [
            'MATCH (user:User)',
            'WHERE ID(user) = {userId}',
            'RETURN user',
        ].join('\n'),
        params: {
            userId: parseInt(id)
        }
    }

    db.cypher(qp, function (err, result) {
        if (err) return callback(err);
        callback(null, result[0]['user']);
    });
};
```

seems to have been replaced with:

```
session
  .run( "MATCH (weapon:Weapon) WHERE weapon.name CONTAINS {term} RETURN weapon.name", {term : searchTerm} )
  .subscribe({
    onNext: function(record) {
      console.log("" + record.get("weapon.name"));
    },
    onCompleted: function() {
      session.close();
    },
    onError: function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  });
```

but I can't seem to find a proper description of session methods (.RUN .THEN .SUBSCRIBE, ETC) anywhere.

Also am I correct in that functions such as db.cypher has been replaced in v3.0? I keep getting a "db.cypher is not a function error" which the searches indicate was fixed in v2.

Answer (score 0):

There is a full documentation for the drivers in the Neo4j manual:

- http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/#driver-manual-index
- API docs: http://neo4j.com/docs/api/javascript-driver/current/

Comment: Hi Michael, I have read both documents more than once and neither of them provide an answer to my questions. except for in code the .xxxx (.run .then etc) appears nowhere in the documents. both do a good job of describing the construct of the driver but not the .methods. Also you didn't answer my second question.....your help is much appreciated ..thanks